# put a struct with vector into buffer with memcpy

Tags: c++, struct, segmentation-fault

```
struct packet {
    uint8_t originating_node;
    uint32_t seq_num;
    uint32_t num_pairs;
    vector<cost_pair> pairs;
 }
```

I am trying to put it into a char array buffer for UDP, I am able to receive the first 3 numbers but not the vector (Seg fault) when I transfer it back to a struct with mempy. How should I do this? Is there anything special that I should do with size of vector? Thanks a lot

Comment: You can't use `memcpy()` with non-POD classes. You can't put a `std::vector` in a UDP packet, it contains all the housekeeping data, not just the values.

Comment: If you're doing C++ then write a stream operator for your struct to handle serializing it.

Comment: To show that what you were trying to do could never work, the call you used to pass the data probably used `sizeof(packet)` as one of the parameters.  If your vector was empty or contained 10,000 items, you would have seen that `sizeof(packet)` doesn't change.  So how would you have expected this to work?

Comment: on ubuntu 15.10, g++ 5.2.1. a std;:vector is 24 bytes, filled or empty, with uint8_t or uint64_t.

Comment: The problem is that you have to write the *data* that the vector represents to the buffer, not the vector itself.  If the vector contains 10 `cost_pair`s, then you write 10 `cost_pair`s.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Do you mean I can do it by looping over the pairs, mempy it to the buffer, then reconstructing it back on the other end?

Comment: Yes @soulless. You will probably want to prepend a count and perhaps sizeof(cost_pair) if that can change.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys